# Trouble getting quiz in javascript to function

Tags: javascript, css

i'm new to javascript and still don't really have a grasp on it. I'm creating a quiz and i'm not sure how to get the quiz questions and answers to pop up. Currently I just have a index page that states "Welcome to the JavaScript Quiz! This quiz is timed!" and has a "start quiz" button. I would like the quiz to start once the "start quiz" button is clicked. (This will be timed, but I haven't figured that out yet).

```
var body = document.body;
var h1El = document.createElement('h1');
var h3El = document.createElement('h3');
var infoEl = document.createElement('div')
var buttonEl = document.createElement('button');[enter image description here][1]

//Using variables to display text and append elements to the body
h1El.textContent = 'Welcome to the JavaScript Quiz!';
h1El.setAttribute('style', 'margin:auto; width:100%; padding:50px 0px 0px 0px; text-align:center;');
body.appendChild(h1El);

h3El.textContent = 'This quiz is timed! Incorrect answers will impact your final score!';
h3El.setAttribute('style', 'margin:auto; width:50%; padding:0px 0px 20px 0px; text-align:center;');
body.appendChild(h3El);

buttonEl.textContent = "Start Quiz";
buttonEl.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50%; margin-left:25%; margin-right:25%; text-align:center;');
body.appendChild(buttonEl);


//Start of quiz questions
var questions = [
    {
        question: "What is JavaScript?",
        choices: ["Coffee Maker", "Text Editor", "Programming Language"],
        answer: "Programming Language"
    },
    {
        question: "What are JavaScript Data Types?",
        choices: ["String, Variable, Content","Number, String, Boolean, Object, Undefined", "Math.floor, isCorrect, Array"],
        answer: "Number, String, Boolean, Object, Undefined"
    },
    {
        question: "Which symbol is used for comments in JavaScript?",
        choices: ["//", "/*", "*/", "all of the above"],
        answer: "All of the above"
    },
    {
        question: "What are all of the types of pop up boxes available in JavaScript?",
        choices: ["alert, confirm, prompt", "cardboard,foam,ice", "windows", "all of the above"],
        answer: "alert, confirm, prompt"
    },
    {
        question: "What are the main for loops in JavaScript?",
        choices: ["for, for/in, while", "if, for, null, string, while", "for, do...while, for/in, while"],
        answer: "for, do...while, for/in, while"
        
    }
]


//Creating a function that will iterate through questions
var createQuizAction = function () {
    document.querySelector("questions").textContent = 

}


buttonEl.addEventListener("click", createQuizAction);
```

Comment: What is holding you back to write the function `createQuizAction`? You'll need to get a question, display it, get the user's answer, ...etc. There are surely many examples out there, just search on quiz and javascript. But you should show your effort, and then focus your question on the problem you encounter when trying.

Comment: Try breaking your problem down into much smaller problems. What's the first thing you think you need to do that you don't know how to do? Search for that. If you can't find a Stack Overflow question that covers it, ask a new question for that specifically. Rinse and repeat.